# How do I call a function on a view when the @ObservedObject is updated

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, observable

I have an Observed Object that's working properly. When I update a String, the label updates.

However, I have a Bool that needs to call a custom function when it changes inside of an Observable Object. When the Bool is set to true, I need to flash the background color for 0.1 seconds.

```
class Event: ObservableObject {
    static let current = Event()
    
    @Published var name = ""
    @Published var pass = false
}

struct EnterDistanceView: View {
    @ObservedObject var event = Event.current

    //when event.pass == true, call this
    func flash() {
        //UI update of flash
    }

}
```

How do I call a method when a property inside of the @ObservedObject changes? Is this possible, or do I need to create

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `onReceive` to do imperative actions when a published value changes:

```
struct EnterDistanceView: View {
    @ObservedObject var event = Event.current

    func flash() {
        //UI update of flash
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello world")
            .onReceive(event.$pass) { value in
                if value {
                    //do your imperitive code here
                    flash()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Inside your `flash` method, I assume you'll want to change the value of a `@State` variable representing the screen color and then use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` to change it back shortly thereafter.